# Is it a good idea to use GRASS Algorithms for Geoprocessing in a Server Environment?

Tags: python, geoprocessing, grass-gis, open-source-gis, web-service

I´m designing a web-service to run in a server environment that will do some geoprocessing actions to datasets uploaded by users and send the results back.

I´m programming in Python, and so far I´ve been using different GRASS algorithms to do the geoprocessing. Which means, I´m using a lot of code that looks like this:

```
grass.run_command("v.buffer", input="a", output="b", type="line", distance=c)
```

Does anyone have experience in using GRASS-algoriths in a server environment? Is it a good idea to use GRASS or should I better be using other libraries (e.g. because they are faster or more stable?). It has to be OpenSource, since we don´t have the budget for ArcGIS Server, etc.

Comment: I see no reason why using GRASS in a server is any different to a client. You need to ensure that you trust the input data (sanitise it if necessary), you need to make sure that it has appropriate performance, it meets your organisational needs, etc. None of that is server (or client) specific though. Can you expand your question to tell us what you are concerned about?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brad. I´m working quite some time with GIS already, but I´m pretty new to anything that is webservice/server related. That´s why my first idea was to just move to the server what I know from desktop GIS  already (e.g. GRASS GIS algorithms). I was just feeling a little bit unsecure if I could do that without any problems. That´s why wanted to ask if someone has experience with offering GRASS geoprocessing services on a server. The better, if there is no reason to difference between desktop or server environment.

Answer (score 4):

Consider to use GRASS GIS 7 for this. While it yet officially released it is much faster and also offers http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WPS support. Ourselves, we use it to process raster and vector data on a cluster in the multi-terabyte range.

See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Category:Massive_data_analysis

Comment: Thanks markusN. I´ll follow your suggestion and will use GRASS 7 instead of 6.4.3 which I´m currently using. Do you have any links which point out the differences between the two versions?

Comment: Sure, please check http://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/ which references a more detailed page through the link "more than 10,000 improvements..."

Comment: Thanks, interesting link. If I understand you right, there should be no problem using GRASS for Server geoprocessing. If you wanna refrase your answer a little bit, so it answers my question, I would accept it.

Comment: You want to only solve your buffer calculation or general geoprocessing? That makes quite a difference and  I don't know how you want me to edit my answer... Vector/raster/image processing, small/big data, interactive user/overnight jobs, and so on. There are many considerations...

Comment: I wanna do more than just buffer calculations, but general geoprocessing, including datum transformations, etc.. It´s quite a few steps. The datasets will be vector and rather small. The user will upload the data and then start the geoprocessing process with a button. The geoprocessing generally lasts around 10 seconds. The user can download the result.

Comment: Then you may want to check http://zoo-project.org/ which can use GRASS GIS as backend (we use that in a couple of projects).